# Type Error: Datatype not understood and trying to use methods from another class

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, oop, physics

I have a class, `Ball` which is as follows:

```
class Ball():
   
    def __init__(self, pos = np.array([0,0]), vel = np.array([0,0]), mass = 1, radius = 1):
        self.mass = mass
        self.radius = radius
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = vel
        self.patch = pl.Circle(self.pos, self.radius, fc = 'r')

    def move(self, dt):
        self.dt = dt
        self.pos = np.add((self.pos),(np.dot((self.vel),self.dt)))


    def time_to_collision(self, other):
        self.other = other
        #print(self.pos, other.pos)
        self.posdif = np.subtract(self.pos, other.pos)
        self.veldif = np.subtract(self.vel, other.vel)
        self.posdif = np.subtract(self.pos, other.pos)
        self.veldif = np.subtract (self.vel, other.vel)
        self.raddif = self.radius - other.radius
        return (-2*np.dot(self.posdif, self.veldif) ....
    
   def collide(self, other):
        self.other = other
        return self.vel - (np.dot(self.veldif, self.posdif)*self.posdif)/(np.dot(self.posdif,self.posdif))
```

I have not written the full `return` line for `time_to_collision` as it is quite long, but I can provide it if necessary (I don't think it is relevant). There is also a subclass/daughter class, of ball, called `Container` which is simply a ball of radius 10, held stationary, defined as follows:

```
class Container(Ball):

    def time_to_collision(self, other):
        self.other = other
        return (-2*np.dot(self.posdif, self.veldif) + np.sqrt(4*(np.dot(self.posdif, self.veldif)**2)-4*np.dot(self.veldif, self.veldif)*(np.dot(self.posdif, self.posdif)-np.dot(self.raddif, self.raddif))))/(2*np.dot(self.veldif, self.veldif))
    
    def collide(self, other):
        self.other = other
        if ((other.vel[0] > 1) or (other.vel[1] < 1)):
            return np.array(-1*other.vel[0], other.vel[1])
        if ((self.vel[0] < 1) or (self.vel[1] > 1)):
            return np.array(other.vel[0], -1*other.vel[1])
```

`move` takes the original position vector (a 2d numpy array) and moves it to a new position based on a time input `dt` and a velocity vector (2d numpy array).

`time_to_collision` calculates the length of time between two ball objects colliding, based on their initial position vectors and velocity vectors.

`collide` performs a collision, and gives the velocity of the ball after it has collided.

I am trying to use these methods in another class, `Simulation`, defined as follows:

```
class Simulation():
    def __init__(self, ball = Ball(), container = Container()):
        self._container = container
        self._ball = ball
    

    def next_collision(self):
        
        self._pos = self._ball.move(self._container.time_to_collision(self._ball)) 
        self._vel = self._container.collide(self._ball)
        print('new pos at', self._pos, 'new vel at', self._vel)
```

As you can see, the Simulation class takes in a Ball object, and a Container object. Then, using the `next_collision` method, it is supposed to calculate the time between a collision of the ball and the container wall using `self._container.time_to_collision`, and then that time is `dt` which is then used in `self._ball.move` to move the ball to that position. Once that happens, `self._container.collide` is supposed to calculate the new velocity of the ball after colliding with the wall. In this next_collision method, I used self._container for the "self" part of the time_to_collision and collide functions, as collisions between a ball and a container have different outcomes to a collision between two balls.

In this case, if the ball has an x-component greater than 1 and a y component less than 1, then the x co-ordinate of the vector/numpy array (index 0) should be multipled by -1. For balls with an x-component lower than 1 and a y-component higher than 1, then it is the y co-ordinate of the vector/numpy array which is to be multiplied by -1.

However, when I create a ball object, a container object, and then created a simulation object using the ball and the container,

running
`test = Simulation(b1, con)` where b1 and con are a ball of radius 1, position vector (1,0) and velocity (3, 0). Then, running..

`test.next_collision()`

yields the following console response:

```
  File "<ipython-input-119-01a65c29a21e>", line 1, in <module>
    test.run(10, True)

  File "C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\y2python\y2python\y2 computing project.py", line 124, in run
    self.next_collision()

  File "C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\y2python\y2python\y2 computing project.py", line 114, in next_collision
    self._vel = self._container.collide(self._ball)

  File "C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\y2python\y2python\y2 computing project.py", line 90, in collide
    return np.array(-1*other.vel[0], other.vel[1])

TypeError: data type not understood
```

I suspect it may be due to how I was trying to access the elements of numpy array.

Comment: Most of your question is irrelevant.  The problem is the `np.array(-1*other.vel[0], other.vel[1])`.  The second argument to `np.array` is supposed to be a `dtype` (check the docs).  You used `other.vel()`.  Read, and REREAD, the docs of the problem function, in this case `np.array`.

Comment: You might intend to be calling `np.array((-1*other.vel[0], other.vel[1]))`?

Comment: @Blckknght that seems to have fixed it, thank you!